# How to check your gem list on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I know the command that works to do this, but I don't understand why. What is `` `...` `` doing in this context.

I know I can run:

```
heroku console
`gem list`
```

or

```
heroku console
`gem list`.split("\n")
```

to get a nice output, but I don't understand what these are doing. Why the ``` `` ```?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've updated this in-case someone happens to come across `heroku console` as it's been disabled.

```
heroku run gem list
```

Show gems installed via :git

```
heroku run bundle show
```

Comment: I'm finding that this doesn't display gems installed via git. Is there any way to see those gems?

Comment: According to the Bundler Documentation, gems from git sources will not show up in gem list because the gem command cannot process them, so Bundler has to do all of the work by itself. Bundler stores these gems in its own location instead. You can do ``heroku run bundle show`` instead

Answer (score 8):

The back ticks effectively making a system call and return the response that was written to stdout. Take a look at the [Kernel ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001408) for more info.

Comment: so, in plain english this basically means it lets you step out of the rails environment you're running on the server and issue a command to the server system itself???

Comment: In plain English that's pretty much it, yes.

Answer (score 7):

`heroku console` is basically running an irb console on the remote computer, so you're in a ruby console when you do it. The backticks (`) are a standard way to run a system command in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, you can run a system command either by using [`Kernel#exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001438) or by placing the contents in backticks. This is the same as typing `gem list` on the command line and getting the result back as a string.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
heroku run 'gem list'
```

Becouse

```
heroku console
```

is removed from heroku